# Python Inserting multiple content from BeautifulSoup into Oracle table

Tags: python, regex, oracle, beautifulsoup

I need to insert a text (War & Peace - https://archive.org/stream/warandpeace030164mbp/warandpeace030164mbp_djvu.txt) into an Oracle table.

I have created a table with 2 cols:

ID - PK with auto_increment (works fine with testing).
content - this is to be filled with smaller chunks from the larger source file.

My code:

```
html = requests.get('https://archive.org/stream/warandpeace030164mbp/warandpeace030164mbp_djvu.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
war_and_peace = soup.pre.get_text()
#war_and_peace = war_and_peace.replace("'", "''")


paragraphs = war_and_peace.split('\n\n')
paragraphs[:] = [p for p in paragraphs if len(p)] # elimiates blank paragraphs

para_chunk = 0

con = cx_Oracle.connect('james/james@192.168.0.24/XE')
ver = con.version.split(".")
print (con.version)
cur = con.cursor()

for p in (paragraphs):
    para_chunk += 1
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages (content) VALUES (\'%s\')" %(paragraphs[para_chunk]))    

con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

However, I get an Oracle error ORA-12899: value too large for column.

Looking at the source text, there are no chunks that exceed this value, so I think I am doing something wrong in my if statement. Can I increment the paragraphs [value] like this? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated - I'm at my wit's end!!!

Thanks in advance - James

DDL for table:

```
DDL:
  CREATE TABLE "JAMES"."PAGES" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CONTENT" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT "PAGES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

Comment: The size of the field content of table pages is too small for the value that you are trying to insert. You should either change the size of the field or change the type of the field to something like CLOB, as it looks like you are trying to insert the whole text of the book.

Comment: Yes this was my first thought, however I have tried to break up the values into small chunks with the code you see in my post. The col value is 200 chars, the max insert size is about 600 chars. So I don't think the issue is with the db constraints, I think I'm not breaking the source text into chunks properly.

Comment: It's not db constraint, it's simple size of the table column. Can we see its DDL? Also, Unicode charactersets require more than one byte for a symbol. Have you tried inserting just couple of symbols?

Comment: Do you know, I think I  might have stumbled upon the problem - and I believe it's in my if loop. the line: %(paragraphs[para_chunk]))  - shouldn't this be %(p[para_chunk])) ? I don't think I'm iterating properly. I modded my script and now get a different error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here.
I haven't tried inserting some symbols no - good idea. Let me grab the DDL for that column...

Comment: I'll add DDL to main post as is too long for comment space...


INSERT INTO pages (content) VALUES ('/\!"£$%^&*()_-+={}'); - worked fine!

Comment: I guess all you have to do now is to print the text for every insert before execution and see exactly what insert is a problem .  You split the book by paragraphs, which could be very long. Try splitting by lines `\n`?

Comment: I have tried this :(

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem in my code. It was my for loop that what the problem (as I suspected).

The correct way to loop for me is:

```
for para in paragraphs:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages (content) VALUES (\'%s\')" %(para))
```

The rest of the script is the same except I can remove the para_chunk variable :)

Thanks for all your input stee1rat